# Selecting rows with shared values in two distinct fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I searched around for this but all I can find are answers on how to select rows  with the same value in both fields. I'm trying to select rows using PostgreSQL that share values in two fields with any other row in the table.

As an example:

```
id    col1     col2
1     A        X
2     A        Y
3     A        X
4     B        Y
5     B        Y
6     B        X
```

In this case I'd want to select rows 1, 3, 4 and 5. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col1, col2) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm Gordon! I appreciate your time.